# Vuetify Editable Table

Tags: vuetify.js

guys! I'd like to edit the table items by pressing the tab key. Do you know how can I modify v-data-table allowing to edit the items like [this](https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/jquery/tables/editable/)?

Answer (score 0):

Inside the v-data-table I create a template with a v-text-field, in which the items can be editable.